# Failed to find dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: proxy, android-studio, arcgis

I follow [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/install-and-set-up.htm) steps for using arcgis android api, but android studio didn't find anything for me. Another thing I'm connecting internet via proxy settings in my work office. I made proxy settings in File > Settings > HTTP Proxy (Manuel Proxy Configuration) My credentials and hostname are true.

Here my error code

```
  Error:Failed to find: com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.5
  Open File
  Open in oject Structure dialog
```

edit :

my build-gradle Project fle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis'
    }
}
}
```

and my module gradle file;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.salih.saaaa"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.5'
}
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: The files are there - http://dl.bintray.com/esri/arcgis/com/esri/arcgis/android/arcgis-android/10.2.5/
must be the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I know where the files are but i am not able to add this files in android studio. I have to add by  compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.5' code.

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your gradle script? the `repositories` and `dependencies` closures?

Comment: I've added in post. Only thing i want to say is I'm connecting internet via proxy, When i try this installing step at my home it has done. Now we minimized problem I think it was about proxy settings but i define proxy settings in android studio. Is there another places to specify proxy settings ? I've just added proxy settings in Android Studio > File > Settings > HTTP Proxy (Manuel Proxy Configuration)

Comment: My bet would be adding [proxy settings to Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) solves the issue. Let me know if it does, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: İt worked perfectly. You are perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since build is performed by Gradle, configuring proxy in Android Studio is not enough (or, to be more precise, has nothing to do with the build).
You need to [configure proxy settings in Gradle itself](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy).

Comment: It has done good to me but. I tried in my office. Where can i put the codes in gradle.properties file ? When I add this code to gradle.properties İt does not recognize anything and could not downladed anything still say can not find file.

Comment: `gradle.properties` file should be located in `~/.gradle` folder.

Answer (score -1):

Settings -> Compiler -> Gradle -> Enabled offline Work then  Save and Apply changes.